# int as boolean expressions Eclipse-Java

Tags: java, eclipse, boolean-expression

Why does Eclipse tell me

```
int a = 4;
if (a) {
    //do stuff
}
```

is wrong, or `Cannot convert from integer to boolean`?

I'm used to writing things like that in C, C++, and thought Java was fine with that too. Is it how Eclipse works? Or is it how Java works? Is there any workaround?

Comment: That's just how Java works. C++ and C are fine with it. Try `if(a != 0)` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java, unlike C++, had a built-in boolean type from its beginnings.
Therefore, it had no need to use integers as booleans.

Disallowing implicit conversion of integer to boolean prevents the infamous `if (x = 4)` bug in most cases.

Comment: Ugh.. that's annoying.. I mean, it feels good to type less/ do two things in one line like `if (x = b)`, instead of
    `x = b;
    if (x != 0) ...;`
:) thank you though.

Comment: You can still type less / do two things in one line, you just must use the correct syntax: `if ((x = b) != 0)`

Comment: well, that's not exactly typing less ;)

Answer (score 4):

In java boolean literls can only have **true** and **false** values. 0 and 1 doesnt work in java as boolean.

FROM [java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf):

> **The boolean type has two values, represented by the boolean literals true and false**

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that in C there is no specific type `boolean` - instead any non-0 integer evaluates to a boolean "true".  Thus in your C code:

```
if(a)
```

`a` is assigned the value 4, which is non-0 - and the condition is evaluated as `true`

In java, there's a fundamental type `boolean` and the value of the conditional inside `if` must be of this type.

```
a=4
```

in Java assigns 4 to `a` and returns the final result of evaluation as `integer value 4`, however type `boolean` is expected - hence you're getting a compile-time error about the incompatible types.

Answer (score 0):

if(a != 0), for int variable a, does the same in Java as if(a) in C or C++.

More generally, it is very important to realize that Java is not a dialect of C or C++. The strongest similarity is in superficial appearance. Java has to be learned as a different language. You will get very frustrated if you depend on C or C++ knowledge when writing Java. Many of the idioms you are used to will not work, and you will not know the idioms that do work.